# In c#, how do I test/get/set Registry keys that may or may not exist?

Tags: c#, windows, registry

I need to test a key, set a key, and clear a key and in all cases the full path and key values might not actually exist. I thought the commands would account for that by returning false if part of the path doesn't exist on check and creating the path on set if it didn't exist, but that seems to not be the case.

```cs
        
        internal bool DownloadGroupByOff()
        {
            using (RegistryKey hku = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64))
            {
                using (RegistryKey explore = hku.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{885A186E-A440-4ADA-812B-DB871B942259}"))
                {
                    if (GetValueInt(explore,"GroupView") == 0)
                        return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        public void DownloadGroupByEnable()
        {
            using (RegistryKey hku = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64))
            {
                using (RegistryKey explore = hku.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{885A186E-A440-4ADA-812B-DB871B942259}", true))
                {
                    explore.DeleteValue("GroupView");
                    explore.DeleteValue("Mode");
                }
            }
        }

        public void DownloadGroupByDisable()
        {
            using (RegistryKey hku = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64))
            {
                using (RegistryKey explore = hku.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{885A186E-A440-4ADA-812B-DB871B942259}", true))
                {
                    explore.SetValue("", "Downloads");
                    explore.SetValue("GroupView", "0");
                    explore.SetValue("Mode", "4");
                }
            }
        }
```

So what I'd like to know is the cleanest way to handle this problem. I could write a quick function that breaks the paths up, tests each level, and adds the subkey if it's not there already, but I'd rather not do that if there's a more elegant or built-in way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was hunting around and may have found a clean way to do it.

First, I created a function to test then create if necessary:

```cs
        // Helper because apparently it won't do this on its own
        public RegistryKey openCreate(RegistryKey baseKey, string path)
        {
            RegistryKey test = baseKey.OpenSubKey(path);

            var reg = baseKey.OpenSubKey(path, true);
            if (reg == null)
            {
                reg = baseKey.CreateSubKey(path);
            }
            return reg;
        }
```

Then I use it as follows:

```cs
        internal bool DownloadGroupByOff()
        {
            // Using "using" to handle auto-close when it leaves this code block (so we don't have to manually close before returning)
            using (RegistryKey localMachine = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64))
            {
                using (RegistryKey explore = localMachine.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{885A186E-A440-4ADA-812B-DB871B942259}")){
                    if (explore == null || GetValueInt(explore, "GroupView") != 0)
                        return false;
                }               
                using (RegistryKey explore = localMachine.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\ComDlg\{885A186E-A440-4ADA-812B-DB871B942259}")){
                    if (explore == null || GetValueInt(explore, "GroupView") != 0)
                        return false;
                }               
                using (RegistryKey explore = localMachine.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\ComDlgLegacy\{885A186E-A440-4ADA-812B-DB871B942259}")){
                    if (explore == null || GetValueInt(explore, "GroupView") != 0)
                        return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
        public void DownloadGroupByEnable()
        {
            RegistryKey localMachine = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);
            // Adding false to this command says not to throw an exception if the key doesn't exist - just ignore
            localMachine.DeleteSubKeyTree(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{885A186E-A440-4ADA-812B-DB871B942259}", false);
            localMachine.DeleteSubKeyTree(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\ComDlg\{885a186e-a440-4ada-812b-db871b942259}", false);
            localMachine.DeleteSubKeyTree(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\ComDlgLegacy\{885A186E-A440-4ADA-812B-DB871B942259}", false);
            localMachine.Close();
        }

        public void DownloadGroupByDisable()
        {
            RegistryKey localMachine = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);
            
            RegistryKey explore = openCreate(localMachine,@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\ComDlg\{885a186e-a440-4ada-812b-db871b942259}");
            explore.SetValue("", "Downloads");
            explore.SetValue("GroupView", "0");
            explore.SetValue("Mode", "4");
            explore.Close();

            explore = openCreate(localMachine, @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\ComDlgLegacy\{885a186e-a440-4ada-812b-db871b942259}");
            explore.SetValue("", "Downloads");
            explore.SetValue("GroupView", "0");
            explore.SetValue("Mode", "4");
            explore.Close();

            explore = openCreate(localMachine, @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{885a186e-a440-4ada-812b-db871b942259}");
            explore.SetValue("", "Downloads");
            explore.SetValue("GroupView", "0");
            explore.SetValue("Mode", "4");
            explore.Close();

            localMachine.Close();
        }
```

I'm open to suggestions for any way this can be improved/cleaned up.